# Poisson point process in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, probability, poisson

I am new with poisson point process. I did one simluation (matlab) as below. **My intensity lambda = 50**;

```
clear all;
lambda=50;
 npoints = poissrnd(lambda);
  pproc = rand(npoints, 2);
  plot(pproc(:, 1), pproc(:, 2), '.');
```

Then I have plot,
[image]

However, the link

http://connor-johnson.com/2014/02/25/spatial-point-processes/

showed me that when intensity **lamuda = 0.2, smaller than 1** , he got

[image]

The link also showed the code in Python.Please check it.

Here is my question, why intensity is **smaller than 1**, he still can plot something here? If I let my code's lamda = 0.2, there will be no value to plot. I think I miss something about Poisson point process? or it's a programming problem? I want to simulate this lambda = 0.2 in matlab.

Thank you so much for your help.

total lambda = 0.4. I want to have 100 unit. This means unit intensity = 0.4 * 100 = 40.   thank you so much.

```
 la=0.4;
 lala=0.4*100;
  npoints = poissrnd(lala);

  pproc = rand(npoints, 2);

  plot(pproc(:, 1).*100, pproc(:, 2).*100, '.');
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, there's a misunderstanding of the math. Look at the example more closely: the *rate of events per unit time per unit area* is 0.2, but lambda (the argument to the `poisson` function) is not 0.2. Your code only considers *one unit of area*, which will *usually* get zero events per unit time (but sometimes 1 or more). This isn't really a programming problem (thus I'm not leaving this as an Answer)

Comment: Note that you're just plotting a uniform distribution; the Poisson distribution is only used once to get a number of points. Edit: the author does point out, "the only thing Poisson about this is the number of points."

Comment: @Lack But a Poisson point process is just that: a Poisson number of points with uniform spatial distribution

Comment: @LuisMendo What do you mean by "Poisson number"? Is there some "Poissonness" that sticks around with `npoints` after is assigned? ;-)

Comment: @Lack Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are right. I go zero events per unit time. that's why I can not have the figure.  Could you please give me more detail about this? and How can I fix it for intensity smaller than 1? If there is a related link, it will be helpful.  I am still learning PPP now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Lack Dear Lack, I just edit my question. Could you please check the code for me very quick. It's short.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @LuisMendo Hey, bro. I just re-edit.  I think Lack is right. Please check it.

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution should be following. 
(Note : Two different methods of drawing PPP spatial distribution)

```
clear all;
clc;
close all;

lambda=50;

%Method 1
pproc  = poissrnd(lambda, 100, 2);
size(pproc)
plot(pproc(:, 1), pproc(:, 2), '.');
title('Poisson with poissrnd')

%Method 2
pproc2 = random('Poisson', lambda, 100, 2);
size(pproc2)
figure;
plot(pproc2(:, 1), pproc2(:, 2), '.');
title('Poisson with Random statement')
```

Answer (score 1):

total lambda = 0.4. I want to have 100 unit. This means unit intensity = 0.4 * 100 = 40. thank you so much.

```
 la=0.4;
 lala=0.4*100;
  npoints = poissrnd(lala);

  pproc = rand(npoints, 2);

  plot(pproc(:, 1).*100, pproc(:, 2).*100, '.');
```

Please check the figure in my question at the end.